# Custom layout needs to inflate xml widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-inflate

I have a custom `LinearLayout`.  Inside that layout I want to place a couple widgets.  I could create the widgets at runtime, but would rather load them from XML.

What I have below works, but I believe it is creating two `LinearLayouts`, one inside the other.  I'd like to simply, in this example, create the `Butto`n and `EditText` inside the `CustomLayout`.  Using XML, how can I do this?

Here is a bit more detail (edit: below this example, I've included a corrected version):

```
<com.example.test.MyActivity
  ... />
  <LinearLayout
    ... />
    <com.example.test.CustomLayout  ***** this is the custom linear layout
      android:id="@+id/custom"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <View
      ... other stuff ... />
</com.example.test.MyActivity>
```

And here's the XML for the CustomLayout contents:

```
<LinearLayout
  ... />
  <Button
    ... />
  <EditText
    ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the code for LinearLayout:

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout
{
  public CustomLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    Activity act = (Activity)context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.custom_layout, this, false);
    addView (view);
  }
  ...
}
```

**Corrected Version**

```
<com.example.test.MyActivity
  ... />
  <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/outer_layout
   ... />

    ... other stuff ... 
  </LinearLayout>
</com.example.test.MyActivity>
```

And here's the XML for the CustomLayout contents:

```
<merge
  ... />
  <Button
    ... />
  <EditText
    ... />
</merge>
```

The code to instantiate CustomLayout

```
public void addCustomLayout()
{
  LinearLayout outerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.outer_layout);
  CustomLayout customLayout = new CustomLayout (getContext(), null);
  outerLayout.addView (customLayout, 0);
}
```

And finally, the code for CustomLayout:

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout
{
  public CustomLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    Activity act = (Activity)context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.custom_layout, this, true);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Have You tired: <com.example.test.CustomLayout ...> <View.../><View ../></com.example.test.CustomLayout>? what is the result? Have You other linearlayout methods overridden?

Comment: Please don't start every question with *android: title...* . All you have to do is tag the question with the `android` tag, every user will know that the question is about android.

Comment: makes sense, and thanks for cleaning up my titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I have below works, but I believe it is creating two
>   LinearLayouts, one inside the other.

Indeed you'll have an extra `LinearLayout`(from the xml layout which contains the `Button` and the `EditText`) in `CustomLayout`. To avoid this you have at your disposal the `merge` tag. You'll use it like this:

```
<merge
  ... />
  <Button
    ... />
  <EditText
    ... />
</merge>
```

Then in your `CustomLayout` constructor:

```
super(context, attrs);
Activity act = (Activity)context;
LayoutInflater inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.custom_layout, this, true); // addView is not needed anymore
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It actually took a bit more to get this to work.  When I first made the changes, I got the error "merge can be used only with a valid viewgroup root".  To fix that, I removed the XML referring to the custom layout and instead created it in my code with **new CustomLayout (...)** followed by a call to **addView**.  I'll update my post with the correction.